# Calculate Remaning Date Without Joda Time

Tags: android, date, time, calendar

I've spent an hour going through stackoverflow trying to find a proper way of calculating the remaining Days, hours, minutes and seconds remaining without using JODA-Time. I wish to keep things simple as possible.

I am seeking to do the following (Please provide declarations of instances, I am not sure as to whether to us Longs, Time or Calendar objects etc):

```
difference =  endingDate-currentTime
```

Then set a textView to the time remaining with DD:HH:MM:SS format

In other words, what is the best method to use? (Timezone is not important) How can I set the ending date to for example December 31, 2013 and what type is my ending date? Is it a time, date or calendar object? I want to then subtract my current date from my ending date to display the remaining days left until December 31, 2013. In the format of DD:HH:MM:SS

Thank you! The help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to handle daylight saving changes to the local time zone? Without that, it's reasonably simple to go from "difference in milliseconds" to "difference in days, hours, minutes, seconds".

Comment: @JonSkeet Would using Time currentTime = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone()); be appropriate? How would I create the EndingDate? For example, setting the endingDate to 12/31/2013?  And please excuse me if I appear confusing,  Its 2am.

Comment: @JonSkeet I clarified my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll leave you to work out how to divide the `difference` variable to get days, hours, etc. But this is how I'd do the rest of it.

```
Calendar endCalendar = new Calendar();

// Set end to 31th Dec 2013 10:15:30 am local time
endCalendar.set(2013, 11, 31, 10, 15, 30);

long localEndTimeInMillis = endCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
long localCurrentTimeInMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

// Convert to UTC.
// Easy way to compensate if the current and end times are in different DST times
utcEndTimeInMillis = getUTCTimeInMillis(localEndTimeInMillis);
utcCurrentTimeInMillis = getUTCTimeInMillis(localCurrentTimeInMillis);

long difference = utcEndTimeInMillis - utcCurrentTimeInMillis;
```

The method to convert to UTC...

```
public long getUTCTimeInMillis(long localTimeInMillis) {
    return localTimeInMillis - TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() - (TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(new Date(localTimeInMillis)) ? TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings() : 0);
}
```

Comment: This appears to be what I needed thank you for your help. I shall mark this as the answer tomorrow after I place it within my code

Comment: String days = "Days Left: "+(difference/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); is giving me a return of 60 days. When it should be returning 30 days. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Resolved the issue. Its supposed to be endCalendar.set(2013, 11, 31, 10, 15, 30); Months begin with 0.

Comment: @ChallengeAccepted : Ah...sorry about that. Yes, I'd forgotten that some date/time fields are zero-based. Glad you managed to resolve it.